# What is a presentation for the Rham cohomology of a smooth manifold

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, algebraic-topology, de-rham-cohomology

In reading about algebraic topology, I have encountered a question where I am asked to find "a presentation for the de Rham cohomology" of a given smooth manifold.

However, I am unsure what a presentation for the de Rham cohomology is. I have seen group presentations before, but the de Rham cohomology is not just a group.

If anyone could clarify the question I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: Where exactly did you find this?

Comment: The de Rham cohomology of a manifold is a graded commutative algebra. Do you mean a presentation in this sense? Generators and relations?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff That's my best guess, but I do not know what a presentation for a graded commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra is.

Comment: You just need to specify the relations the variable satisfy, along with their homological degrees. For example, if $M$ is the torus, then $H_{\mathsf{dR}}(M)$ is a free graded commutative algebra on two generators $a$ and $b$ of degree $1$. This determines it completely as $a^2=b^2=0$ and $ab=-ba$ gives the top cohomology class in degree $2$. So $H_{\mathsf{dR}}(M) = S(a,b) =\{1,a,b,ab\}$ (the point is that commutative algebras already come with relations $ab=(-1)^{|a||b|}ba$ which imply that $a^2=0$ if $a$ is odd, so indeed this has no (extra) relations at all).